Reverse engineering Data modeling using Erwin tool using salesforce but it's not loading due to high volume
I am trying to make connect of salesforce DB with Erwin data modeling tool for reverse engineering but it's so heavy, it's not loading. Please suggest how can we do or any other way to do using any other tool and technology.
Please suggest the alternative approach how can i do the reverse engineering with salesforce DB
